# How to know subtract two arrays

Tags: c#, sql, .net, arrays, datatable

I have an array of string:

```
private static string[] dataNames = new string[] { "value1", "value2", ..... "value56" };
```

I have a table in my SQL database that contains a column which its type is VARCHAR

I want to know which values that exist in the array and doesn't exist in that column.

#### What I tried

```
var matchingRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
    Where(row => dataNames.Contains(row.Field<string>("ColumnName"), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

where `dt` is the dataTable the contains the results of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table name
```

now I have the matchingValues in `matchingRows` variable and I can transfer it to array usingg `ToArray()`

Now I still need to know how to subtract the `dataNames` array from the `matchingRows` in order to know which values exist in the array and don't exit in the table column.

could you help me in that issue please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all values for this column from table and then use [Except()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.100).aspx) method.

```
var matchingRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => dataNames.Contains(row.Field<string>("ColumnName"), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Select(row => row.Field<string>("ColumnName"));

var diff = dataNames.Except(matchingRows, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: just one last thing please. the array is all capitale letter, which the matchingvalues is sometimes capitale and sometimes small letter, so your answer doesn't work. can you make this except case insensitive ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var columnData = matchingRows.Select(row => row.Field<string>("ColumnName"));
var diff = dataNames.Except(columnData);
```

In order to perform a case insensitive comparison, you need to pass an instance of `IEqualityComparer<string>` to `Except`. Normally, you'd have to implement this interface yourself, but luckily, `StringComparer` provides a few out-of-the-box custom string comparers.

```
var diff = dataNames.Except(columnData, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: matchingrows are DataRows and `dataNames` contains strings

Comment: I already tried that, I got syntax error, if you want I can tell it to you

Comment: @dcastro I got error now that matchingRows does't contains a definition for field

Comment: @dcastro: `matchingRows` is an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` not a single datarow, Farhad shows the correct way in his answer.

Comment: +1 for your efforts with me but the other guy helps me first.

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec Fair enough :)